# PHP Spreadsheet Generator Multiple Cell Span

Tags: php

I was looking around and figured out how to generate a spreadsheet using this basic [tutorial](http://www.lateralcode.com/excel-spreadsheets-php/).

The problem is that I can't figure out how to generate a cell/entry that spans multiple rows/columns (see picture below).

[image: Cell Spanning Rows]

Not quite sure where to post/ask around... any help/pointers appreciated!

Comment: That tutorial just emits a CSV file (which has no formatting options) and calls it an Excel file. It works, but it's really crude and you won't be able to use any formatting at all. You can use a library like [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) to do this, or you really need to start again with a better tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use phpExcel library which have nice set of utility function. For your you can use function `mergeCells()`. As like this

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->mergeCells('A1:A3');
```

For details about phpExcel [click Here!](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks! Seems like the tool I need!